I want to change the motor speed using a script, but error appears
I want to change the motor speed by pressing A and D buttons using a script, but this error appears:
HingeJoint2D does not contain a definition for HingeJoint2D and no accessible extension method HingeJoint2D accepting a first argument of type HingeJoint2D could be found.
I am a complete noob at both unity and C#, please help me understand what I did wrong.
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class motorControler : MonoBehaviour
{
private HingeJoint2D hj;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        hj = GetComponent<HingeJoint2D>();
    }

    public float Speed = 10f;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))

            hj.HingeJoint2D.motor += Speed;

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))

            hj.HingeJoint2D.motor -= Speed;

    }
}


Use hj.motor, not hj.HingeJoint2D.motor.

it fixed something but code still don't working, I don't get it

Well, do you have "Use Motor" checked in the inspector and the limits and such setup properly? There could be many issues outside of this code and "don't working" doesn't explain anything about what is happening.

hj already is of type "HingeJoint2D" so it should just be "hj.motor += Speed"
